How to change value dynamically when i delete multiple images from input file
When i preview images and then i delete one of them, value stays same
 const filesRef = useRef(null);

redux stuff
const initialState = {
    images: [],
};

const productsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "products",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    deleteImg: (state, action) => {
      const payload = action.payload;
      state.images = payload;
    },
  },
});

   <input
          type="file"
          accept="image/*"
          alt="upload image"
          className="product-images-input"
          name="image"
          onChange={e => {
            handleAddImages({ target: e.target });
          }}
          onClick={e => {
            console.log(e.target.value);
            e.target.value = null;
          }}
          multiple
          hidden
          ref={filesRef}
        />

Formally, i can delete image but value stays same, even image is deleted i still can upload to cloud. if i use filesRef.current.value = null in handleDeleteImg function it works if i have one image, but if i have multiple image preview and i delete one, value will be null.
const handleDeleteImg = i => {
    const newImages = images.filter((_, index) => index !== i);
    dispatch(deleteImg(newImages));
  };

     {images.length > 0 && (
        <div className="uploaded-img-container">
          {images.map(({ url, name }, index) => {
            return (
              <article className="img-content" key={index}>
                <img
                  src={url}
                  alt={name || "default name"}
                  key={index}
                  className="uploaded-img"
                  title={name || "default name"}
                />
                <TiDelete
                  className="delete-img"
                  onClick={() => handleDeleteImg(index)}
                />
              </article>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      )}


This might be because value of file input field is controlled by browser and is not directly related to images displayed in your component. We'd need to force React to remount the input element every time an image is deleted. By remounting input element, its value will be reset automatically.
Add a new state variable to hold a key that will be used to force remounting the input element:
const [inputKey, setInputKey] = useState(0);

Then your file input element to use this key
<input
  type="file"
  key={inputKey}
  accept="image/*"
  alt="upload image"
  className="product-images-input"
  name="image"
  onChange={e => {
    handleAddImages({ target: e.target });
  }}
  onClick={e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    e.target.value = null;
  }}
  multiple
  hidden
  ref={filesRef}
/>

At the end when you delete an image, increment key to force remounting
const handleDeleteImg = i => {
  const newImages = images.filter((_, index) => index !== i);
  dispatch(deleteImg(newImages));
  setInputKey(prevKey => prevKey + 1);
};


Yes but, look.  onClick={e => e.target.value = null} when i have image(s) and i select images and then i changed my mind. value is null already. soo, what should i do?

And also, if i have more than one image, then i deleted one, now value is null and i can't upload
